# Magento addons showing 404 page from top menu after update 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, 404-page

I recently updated magento and now when I click an add-on link from the top horizontal menu I get a 404. I have two links from add-ons in this menu, blue ripples slide show and and ES custom menu under CMS. I updated by creating a new install in a new directory then moved modules and my custom layout files over. The add-on links under system/configuration appear to be working fine, for example the lightbox2 app.
I tried to deleted and re-download blue ripples but I still get the 404 page; but the slideshow is still working on the front-end. so is the ES custom menu addon. I didn't delete the database for blue ripples just re-installed the files using magento connect.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've added the a url just in case there's an issue I'm not aware of. I deleted the cache and of course logged out/in like is required whenever a new app is added.

blue ripples url

mysite.com/fresh/test/index.php/brslides/adminhtml_index/index/key/*****/

the cms page url

mysite.com/fresh/test/index.php/adminaccess/cms_page/index/key/*****/

This is driving me insane!

requested XMl file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Blueripples_Slideshow>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </Blueripples_Slideshow>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <slideshow>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Blueripples_Slideshow</module>
                    <frontName>brslides</frontName>
                </args>
            </slideshow>
        </routers>
      </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <slideshow>
                    <file>slideshow.xml</file>
                </slideshow>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
    <global>
        <models>
            <slideshow>
                <class>Blueripples_Slideshow_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>slideshow_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </slideshow>
            <slideshow_mysql4>
                <class>Blueripples_Slideshow_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <slideshow>
                        <table>slideshow</table>
                    </slideshow>
                </entities>
            </slideshow_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <slideshow_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Blueripples_Slideshow</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </slideshow_setup>
            <slideshow_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </slideshow_write>
            <slideshow_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </slideshow_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <slideshow>
                <class>Blueripples_Slideshow_Block</class>
            </slideshow>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <slideshow>
                <class>Blueripples_Slideshow_Helper</class>
            </slideshow>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <default>
        <slideshow>
            <general>
                <enable>0</enable>
                <width>900</width>
                <height>320</height>
                <pause_on_click>false</pause_on_click>
                <portrait>false</portrait>
                <thumbnails>false</thumbnails>
                <bar_position>bottom</bar_position>
                <skin>camera_grey_skin</skin>
            </general>
            <advance>
                <overlayer>false</overlayer>
                <cols>6</cols>
                <rows>4</rows>  
                <sliced_cols>0</sliced_cols>
                <sliced_rows>0</sliced_rows> 
                <time>5000</time>
                <trans_period>3000</trans_period>
                <grid_difference>1500</grid_difference> 
                <fx>random</fx>                 
            </advance>
            <loader>
                <loader_color>CCCCCC</loader_color>
                <loader_bg_color>222222</loader_bg_color>
                <loader_opacity>0.8</loader_opacity>
                <loader_padding>2</loader_padding>
                <loader_stroke>7</loader_stroke>            
            </loader>
            <title>
                <enable_title>1</enable_title>                  
                <width_title>22</width_title>
                <height_title>65</height_title>
                <margin_title>1</margin_title>                          
                <fx_title>fadeFromLeft</fx_title>                       
                <title_bg_color>208510</title_bg_color>
                <font_color_title>FFFFFF</font_color_title>
                <font_size_title>22</font_size_title>   
                <opacity_title>0.9</opacity_title>
                <border_radius_title>20</border_radius_title>           
            </title>
            <description>
                <enable_description>1</enable_description>                  
                <width_description>40</width_description>
                <height_description>35</height_description>
                <margin_description>1</margin_description>                      
                <fx_description>fadeFromRight</fx_description>                      
                <description_bg_color>FFFFFF</description_bg_color>
                <font_color_description>2AB516</font_color_description>         
                <font_size_description>12</font_size_description>
                <opacity_description>0.9</opacity_description>
                <border_radius_description>20</border_radius_description>           
            </description>                  
        </slideshow>
    </default>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <slideshow>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Blueripples_Slideshow</module>
                    <frontName>brslides</frontName>
                </args>
            </slideshow>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: Could you post the `config.xml` file of your module please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin routes are not properly declared in the module.

Since SUPEE-6788, you need to replace the following:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <slideshow>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Blueripples_Slideshow</module>
                <frontName>brslides</frontName>
            </args>
        </slideshow>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

With:

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Blueripples_Slideshow before="Mage_Adminhtml">Blueripples_Slideshow_Adminhtml</Blueripples_Slideshow>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Then move ensure your admin controller is located under `controllers/Adminhtml` folder and is named in a unique way (in your case I would name it `BrslidesController.php`) .

Now to ensure every URL is properly generated, you need to look for the usual URL generator suspects:

- `etc/adminhtml.xml`
- adminhtml layout file (under `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout` or `app/design/adminhtml/base/default/layout`)
- use of the `getUrl` function

Let's assume your old admin route was: `brslides`

You will probably find admin URL declared like this:

- `brslides/adminhtml/index` for the direct URLs
- `<brslides_adminhtml_index>` for the layout handles

You will need to replace those URLs with the new admin route:

- `adminhtml/brslides/index` for the direct URLs
- `<adminhtml_brslides_index>` for the layout handles

NB: I'm using `index` in the examples above, this is an example for the indexAction, you need to replace that piece with your action name for every URLs you will find.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply,  I'll get on this a later today after I wrap up another project.